# Joomla and K2 Soft404 errors

Tags: php, joomla

We are using Joomla for a public site and we are getting a ton of soft 404 errors that all look similar to

```
/?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=xxx
```

where xxx = some numeric id.  Obviously this is some soft of spamming but how do I turn it off in Joomla/K2?

I'm not particularly Joomla oriented but this seems a task I should be able to accomplish if I can get an idea of "where" to fix the code.  The page shows a warning instead of an error

> Warning
>   JUser: :_load: Unable to load user with ID: 35414

so it seems the "page" is actually there but with no content.  I'm guessing some internal handler is spitting this dynamic content out but I want to return 404 in this case.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand the nature of your problem. What do you mean with "Soft 404" errors? Do you have 404 errors or not?

On my K2 websites, I have sometimes "visitors" who try to find holes in K2. I then have many, many accesses of the same page. These visitors try to post comments or somethings else on the articles or user profiles.

Is this a similar thing that is happening on your site?

- Is there a (Joomla) user on your site with ID 35414? If not, you can be pretty sure that someone is trying to hack your site.
- Is the URL always requested by the same user? You can find this in the log files of the Apache server. In such cases I add a "deny from" statement to my .htaccess file.

In case you seriously expect a K2 related issue, I would recommend to post the issue in the [K2 forum](https://www.joomlaworks.net/forum/k2-en). This forum is quite knowledgeable and [JoomlaWorks](https://www.joomlaworks.net/) makes a serious effort to bring good K2 customer support.

Comment: Soft 404 errors are not new they are described here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2409443?utm_source=wnc_655200&utm_medium=gamma&utm_campaign=wnc_655200&utm_content=msg_716501&hl=en  Basically your page returns a blank response.  There is no user of that id and the urls all differ by ID.  The referrer is my own site so pretty sure someone is spamming me in an attempt to find an entry point.  What I want to know is how do I return a 404 in the header since the content here is being generated dynamically?